# How do I show multiple recaptchas on a single page using EWZRecaptchaBundle?

Tags: php, symfony, recaptcha

I'm using [EWZRecaptchaBundle](https://github.com/excelwebzone/EWZRecaptchaBundle), a bundle that provides reCAPTCHA form fields for Symfony.

When I try to render 1 recaptcha it works fine, but when I try 2, it only shows the first.

Is it possible to show multiple recaptchas on a single page using this bundle?

My code:

```
composer.json

"require": {
    ...
    "excelwebzone/recaptcha-bundle": "~1.4.1",
}


AppKernel.php

$bundles = array(
    // ...
    new EWZ\Bundle\RecaptchaBundle\EWZRecaptchaBundle(),
    // ...
);


# app/config/config.yml

ewz_recaptcha:
    public_key:  here_is_your_public_key
    private_key: here_is_your_private_key
    locale_key:  %kernel.default_locale%


//form class
<?php

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('recaptcha', 'ewz_recaptcha', [
            'required'    => true,
            'constraints' => [
                new RecaptchaTrue()
            ],
            'mapped' => false,
        ])


//twig template
<div id="recaptcha_google_div" {% if not signupForm.recaptcha.vars.valid %}class="left"{% endif %}>
    {{ form_widget(signupForm.recaptcha) }}
    {{ form_errors(signupForm.recaptcha) }}
</div>
```

Comment: could you post some code, like twig templates

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers

Answer (score 3):

I looked up this question on google, but sadly found no answer. I managed to find a solution, so here is how I made it work:

First I made a custom form theme:

```
{% block ewz_recaptcha_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% if form.vars.ewz_recaptcha_enabled %}
        {% if not form.vars.ewz_recaptcha_ajax %}
            <script>
                var captchaCallback = function() {
                    var captchas = document.getElementsByClassName('g-recaptcha');

                    for (var i = 0; i < captchas.length; i++) {
                        grecaptcha.render(captchas[i], {
                            'sitekey': '{{ form.vars.public_key }}',
                            'theme': '{{ attr.options.theme }}'
                        });
                    }
                };
            </script>
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-theme="{{ attr.options.theme }}" data-size="{{ attr.options.size }}" data-type="{{ attr.options.type }}" data-sitekey="{{ form.vars.public_key }}" {% if attr.options.expiredCallback is defined %}data-expired-callback="{{ attr.options.expiredCallback }}"{% endif %}></div>
            <noscript>
                <div style="width: 302px; height: 352px;">
                    <div style="width: 302px; height: 352px; position: relative;">
                        <div style="width: 302px; height: 352px; position: absolute;">
                            <iframe src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/fallback?k={{ form.vars.public_key }}"
                                    frameborder="0" scrolling="no"
                                    style="width: 302px; height:352px; border-style: none;"
                            >
                            </iframe>
                        </div>
                        <div style="width: 250px; height: 80px; position: absolute; border-style: none; bottom: 21px; left: 25px; margin: 0; padding: 0; right: 25px;">
                            <textarea id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response"
                                      class="g-recaptcha-response"
                                      style="width: 250px; height: 80px; border: 1px solid #c1c1c1; margin: 0; padding: 0; resize: none;"
                            >
                            </textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </noscript>
        {% else %}
            <div id="ewz_recaptcha_div"></div>

            <script type="text/javascript">
            (function() {
                var script = document.createElement('script');
                script.type = 'text/javascript';
                script.onload = function() {
                    Recaptcha.create('{{ form.vars.public_key }}', 'ewz_recaptcha_div', {{ attr.options|default({})|json_encode|raw }});
                };
                script.src = '{{ form.vars.url_api }}';
                {% if attr.options.defer is defined and attr.options.defer %}script.defer = true;{% endif %}
                {% if attr.options.async is defined and attr.options.async %}script.async = true;{% endif %}
                document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
            })();
            </script>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock ewz_recaptcha_widget %}
```

It's pretty much the same form theme as the default one, except I changed two things. I added a callback function and I removed the google recaptcha api script (to prevent it from calling the callback function twice).

Then you will have to manually load the recaptcha api script in one of your templates:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl={{ app.request.locale }}&amp;onload=captchaCallback&amp;render=explicit" defer async></script>
```

And you need to load your custom form theme wherever your forms are loaded:

```
{% form_theme form 'form/captcha_layout.html.twig' %}
```

That should allow you to have more than one captcha on the same page.

Comment: you deserve all the upvotes imaginable. Its weird the bundle doesnt deal with this automatically